Why ice gathering have failed?
I have implemented webrtc-connection program in javascript (Firefox 112.0.1).
Signalling server is my implementation too (C++).
In some cases JS doesn't establish connection.
I have experimented with the following cases:

Local and remote requests GetUserMedia and both users allow them. Both peers call addTrack() to pass it's video/audio each other.
Network cable is disconnected (it is important - see more).
It works.  
Local and remote peers request GetUserMedia, but local user prohibits access, remote allows it. In this case local peer adds recvonly transceiver instead of calling addTrack(), the remote calls addTrack() to add track to the connection. Network cable is disconnected.
It doesn't establish the webrtc-connection.

Similar to case (2), but the network cable connected to a network.
It works.

All experiments were made on one computer through loopback (127.0.0.1).
It was surprising for me that if I connect the network cable (case 3), then the webrtc connection works good.
But in case 1 it have worked without cable connection!
Unfortunately, the code is large enough. It is not easy to read it.
I'd like to suggest you take a look to logs in HTML format instead for the cases 1, 2, 3 (you can download it and open as HTML) - log1 (ok) - https://pastebin.com/ttJz06Rr, log2 (err) - https://pastebin.com/x9fi0dGZ, log3 (ok) - https://pastebin.com/kKUAyVEK. 
In the logs you can see a sequence of calls and events in local peer.
"Call:" lines shows which functions were called. 
"Event:" lines shows which events were fired. 
I am ready to provide additional information in logs if it will be neccesary. 
So, from the log2 we can see, that after checking in line 24 we have failed in line 47.
But in the log1 in lines 33, 34 the connection gets established.
The question is: why ice-candidates checking may have failed in the case2 ?
What data should I look at in more detail ?
